# How to see, which key is pressed, as seen by unity window manager?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

After a system crash, the shortcuts I use for switching the workplaces with Mod_3 modifier (e.g. Mod_3 + Left to switch workplace left) ceased to work.

I use the following `.Xmodmap` script:

```
remove control = Control_R
clear mod3
add mod3 = Control_R
```

loaded with `xmodmap .Xmodmap`.

The Control_R key is working properly, as reported by `xev`. But `xev` is too much "low level" - it shows physical keys pressed.

I need something that allow me to verify that pressing "right control" together with "left arrow" is seen as `Mod3+Left` to the unity.

Something, that could replace the partially broken `All Settings->Keyboard` window (it was never compatible with the Mod3 compose key).

[image]

---

update:

It appeared, that the shortucts were disabled because the **Desktop Wall** compiz plugin was disabled. Enabling it brought back the functionality. Nevertheless the question stands valid and unanswered.

Comment: this looks too humblesome to me - please check first the activated languages in settings of keyboard - and which keyboard you have activated for these languages (a keyboard with 105 keys - or a keyboard with 99 keys - ) in case you have a German keyboard, it is sufficient only to activate 105 keys (like IBM-Standard) ... this could be easier than above ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these maybe, they don't seem to have a problem with `mod3` (which they display as `Hyper`)

- easystroke

  run twice to show UI, add action, click `command` and change to `key`, then it'll grab and show next keystroke.
- compizconfig-settings-manager (ccsm)

  for example navigate to `general options -> keybindings` and change one of them, then `grab key combination`.